# Поиск элемента в массиве не работает

Tags: php, массивы

```
$couch = array(
'AU' => '0.5',
'RU' => '0.5',
'DE' => '0.5'
);

if (in_array('RU', $couch)) {
echo 'ok';
}
```

Не ищет, как исправить?

Comment: Читайте доки, `in_array` ищет значения, а вам надо искать ключи. Например, так: `isset($couch[$key])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы ищите по значениям, а надо по ключам.

```
if (isset($couch['RU'])) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

isset возвращает false, если значение равно `null`:

```
$a = array ('test' => 1, 'hello' => NULL, 'pie' => array('a' => 'apple'));

var_dump(isset($a['test']));            // TRUE
var_dump(isset($a['foo']));             // FALSE
var_dump(isset($a['hello']));           // FALSE

// Элемент с ключом 'hello' равен NULL, поэтому он считается неопределенным
// Если Вы хотите проверить существование ключей со значением NULL, используйте: 
var_dump(array_key_exists('hello', $a)); // TRUE
```

Если Вы хотите проверить существование ключей со значением NULL, используйте:

или

```
if (array_key_exists('RU', couch)) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

или

```
if (in_array('RU', array_keys($couch))) {
    echo 'ok';
}
```

Comment: Думаю, стоит объяснить разницу между этими двумя подходами, например, на массиве `array('a' => null, 'b' => 'b')`

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверять вот так

```
 $couch = array(
  'AU' => '0.5',
  'RU' => '0.5',
  'DE' => '0.5'
 );

 if (isset($couch['RU'])) {
  echo 'ok';
 }
```

http://php.net/manual/ru/function.in-array.php обратите внимание, что in_array ищет значения.